# Number of Windows in VIM

Tags: vim

I'd like to know how many windows are open in the current tab page from a Vim function; in particular, it would be handy to know if a particular window is the last, eg from an autocmd, in a tab page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm guessing you can do it all with the winnr() command.

[winnr()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#winnr()) by itself tells you the window number you are currently in.
winnr('$') tells you the last window (or window count)

The following would return '1' if you were in the last window, and 0 otherwise:

```
echo winnr() == winnr('$')
```

Taking your example you could then do something like this to execute something only on the last window:

```
:autocmd WinEnter * if winnr() == winnr('$')|echo "Welcome to the last window"|endif
```

Comment: Actually according to vim documentation (http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#winnr%28%29) winnr('$') IS the number of windows on current tab.

Answer (score 6):

You could also do the following:

```
let window_counter = 0
windo let window_counter = window_counter + 1
echo window_counter
```

The `:windo` command runs an ex command in each window of your current tab.

Comment: winnr('$') is sufficient solution. Besides, your code will result in selecting last windows which is rarely required effect of getting window count.

Comment: @AmokHuginnsson, this solution is sufficient also.  Your first point is not really clear.  The second point makes sense, though.